# Networking is disabled after waking up from hibernation sometimes

Tags: 14.04, networking, xfce, hibernate

Sometimes when I hibernate my laptop It's not able to connect to internet(neither ethernet or wi-fi) after waking up. The icon on panel says "Networking disabled" and can't be switched back on by clicking on it as it usually works. Next restart/hibernation/sleep always makes networking work again.

Notes:
I mostly use ethernet on a network that is mac address specific and so far I haven't had same problem anywhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get this problem sometimes, here is how I fix it.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Enter your password, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>